# Negative Weak Correlations

Tags: correlation

I've performed correlation tests and received negative weak correlations using ordinal and interval data. I've tired a log transformation, and still the correlations were the same. I'm looking for a positive weak to moderate correlation with the data. So far, I've done a log transformation, Spearman and Pearson Correlation. You assistance is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should give more background, like what the variables represent and why you want to transform them so that they are positively correlated. It sounds like you are fishing for results in the data that aren't there.

Comment: Why don't you believe the results you are getting? Do you have some prior information or reason to believe that the size and sign of the correlations should be as you state? Please expound.

Comment: In addition to what Dan said, plot your data and post it here if you want good answers to your question.

Comment: Transforming in the hope of making the correlation what you want (or your supervisor wants) is basically data-dredging. Anything you do after that is unlikely to mean much of anything.

Answer (score 1):

This question is hard to answer without knowing more about the actual data and I am sure there is a multitude of transformations that will accomplish what you want, however, justifying why you used that transformation is not trivial.  For example, consider the following two plots.

So, the original correlation of the data is weak and negative (correlation = -0.0508)

[image]

We can transform the the $y$ variable using an exponential transformation such that $z=exp(y)$ and now we have positive correlated data.

[image]

How do you justify an exponential transformation?  Your guess is as good as mine but it could work for you.  Bottom line you need to pick an appropriate transformation for your data and report what you actually find rather than trying to obtain a result that may be artificial (at least my two cents).

Comment: Thanks, my adviser is looking for positive correlations, not me. My intention for the data was to show correlations between spending on certain items (mobile phones, clothe and shoes to peer influence, advertisements and saving-face). I noticed that my subjects were not fully truthful in answering my questions, and knew this would affect any information I was looking for. Although, the correlations are weak and negative, my adviser wants positive correlations. I'm pretty much stuck here.